# SSRS maps Error "unable to determine the spatial data type due to connection error"

Tags: reporting-services, maps, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am creating a map report in SSRS. I have a dataset which has spacial data and it has parameters.I am getting the below error after selecting the dataset for Spatial query

> "unable to determine the spatial data type due to connection error"

I tried with removing the parameters,it worked fine.But my business logic needs Parameters to be passed dynamically.Is there a way i can get through this?

Comment: What data type is the parameter? What data type is the column in SQL table?

Comment: Spatial field has the geometry as datatype.But i am passing another parameter client which is Int.

Comment: Just to confirm your Report Parameter is Int and your dataset parameter is also Int. You cannot have Report Parameter that is Int and the dataset parameter column that is geometry. Need clarification on Report Parameter and the dataset.

Comment: If you are using the wizard as shown here -> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4e413b8-a6fb-4305-bbeb-18a7620ac9b4/creating-a-map-report-using-parameter, ignore the error.

Comment: This posting -> http://clinthuijbers.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/drilldown-functionality-in-maps-ssrs-2008-r2/ helps to explain the reason for the error message.